# NLTK language modeling confusion

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I want to train a language model using NLTK in python but I got into several problems.
first of all, I don't know why my words turn into just characters as I write something like this :

```
s = "Natural-language processing (NLP) is an area of computer science " \
"and artificial intelligence concerned with the interactions " \
"between computers and human (natural) languages."
s = s.lower();


paddedLine = pad_both_ends(word_tokenize(s),n=2);

train, vocab = padded_everygram_pipeline(2, paddedLine)
print(list(vocab))
lm = MLE(2);
lm.fit(train,vocab)
```

and the printed vocab is something like this that is clearly not correct(i don't want to work with characters!),this is part of output.:

```
<s>', '<', 's', '>', '</s>', '<s>', 'n', 'a', 't', 'u', 'r', 'a', 'l', '-', 'l', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'u', 'a', 'g', 'e', '</s>', '<s>', 'p', 'r', 'o', 'c', 'e', 's', 's', 'i', 'n', 'g', '</s>', '<s>', '(', '</s>', '<s>', 'n', 'l', 'p', '</s>', '<s>', ')', '</s>'
```

why my input turns into characters?
i did this work in another way but with no luck :

```
paddedLine = pad_both_ends(word_tokenize(s),n=2);
#train, vocab = padded_everygram_pipeline(2, tokens)
#train = everygrams(paddedLine,max_len = 2);

train = ngrams(paddedLine,2);
vocab = Vocabulary(paddedLine,unk_cutoff = 1);
print(list(train))

lm = MLE(2);
lm.fit(train,vocab)
```

when i run this code my train is absolute nothing,empty! it shows me "[]" !!
wired thing is when i comment at this line from above code:

```
vocab = Vocabulary(paddedLine,unk_cutoff = 1);
```

now my train data is ok and something like this that is correct :

```
[('<s>', 'natural-language'), ('natural-language', 'processing'), ('processing', '('), ('(', 'nlp'), ('nlp', ')'), (')', 'is'), ('is', 'an'), ('an', 'area'), ('area', 'of'), ('of', 'computer'), ('computer', 'science'), ('science', 'and'), ('and', 'artificial'), ('artificial', 'intelligence'), ('intelligence', 'concerned'), ('concerned', 'with'), ('with', 'the'), ('the', 'interactions'), ('interactions', 'between'), ('between', 'computers'), ('computers', 'and'), ('and', 'human'), ('human', '('), ('(', 'natural'), ('natural', ')'), (')', 'languages'), ('languages', '.'), ('.', '</s>')]
```

whats wrong with it? 
by the way, I have to say that I'm not an expert in python or NLTK and it's my first experience.
The next question is how can I use kneser-ney smoothing or add-one smoothing on the training language model? 
and am I doing language model training the right way?
my training data is simple :

```
"Natural-language processing (NLP) is an area of computer science " \
    "and artificial intelligence concerned with the interactions " \
    "between computers and human (natural) languages."
```

thanks.

Comment: kindly consider sharing  an example of the training data few lines will be fine.

Comment: @Inder i edited the post.

Comment: I am not able reproduce the problem, what I did was was `word_tokenize(s)` , and it gave tokenized words.

Comment: @Inder can you post your code so i can test it please?

Comment: Kindly explain what you are asking.

Comment: @Inder i'm asking how i can train my own corpus using NLTK?

Comment: @Inder And why NLTK treat my corpus as characters rather than words?

Comment: @train as in creating your own embeddings??? 

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54979617/610569

Comment: @alvas thanks,how can i calculate perplexity? when i calculate perplexity using my code bigram is more than unigram which is clearly wrong,can u show a sample code there? thanks.

Comment: @alvas i posted a new question here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989825/nltk-perplexity-measure-inversion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `padded_everygram_pipeline` function expects a list of list of n-grams. You should fix your first code snippet as follows. Also python generators are lazy sequences, you can't iterate them more than once.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.lm import MLE
from nltk.lm.preprocessing import pad_both_ends, padded_everygram_pipeline

s = "Natural-language processing (NLP) is an area of computer science " \
    "and artificial intelligence concerned with the interactions " \
    "between computers and human (natural) languages."
s = s.lower()

paddedLine = [list(pad_both_ends(word_tokenize(s), n=2))]

train, vocab = padded_everygram_pipeline(2, paddedLine)

lm = MLE(2)

lm.fit(train, vocab)

print(lm.counts)
```

Comment: It seems to me that there's one more mistake: the line is first padded with `pad_both_ends()` and then with `padded_everygram_pipeline()`, so there will be double padding if I'm correct.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple mistakes in the above answer:

1. "padded_everygram_pipeline function expects a list of list of n-grams" -> No,  If you mean input, it just needs list of list of tokenized word. Not n-grams. It generates n-grams
   2)You don't need to do padding as padded_everygram_pipeline already does it for you. So no need for padded_everygram_pipeline(2, paddedLine)
   One correct way to do this for a single sentence s:

   ```
    tokens = [list((word_tokenize(s))]
    train_data_bigram, padded_sent_list = padded_everygram_pipeline(2, tokens)
   ```

   #To check everygram in result, you can use the following

   for ngramlize_sent in train_data_bigram:

   ```
    #prints unigrams and bigrams

    print(list(ngramlize_sent))

    print()
   ```

   print('----')

   #prints padded sentence i.e. sentence itself is padded

   list(padded_sent_list)

   lm = MLE(2)

   lm.fit(train_data_bigram, padded_sent_list)

   print(lm.counts)

Similarly you can change 2 to 3 in both places and end up testing this with a trigram model.

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer is incorrect. This is the correct answer