# How does ntlk's language model assign a score?

Tags: nlp, nltk

So, I built a simple n-gram language model based on the documentation here: https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.lm.html

But I am a little confused by the score that the language model is producing. Please see the snapshot from the same document:[image]

Below, I check the count of a bigram:
[image]

But when I use `model.score("floral",["print"])`, I get `0` as the output. I am not able to understand why. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have some confuses in the order of function's parameters: 
`model.counts[['floral']]['print']` counts `"floral print"` 
 and 
 `model.score("floral",["print"])` print `P('floral'|'print')` 
 So maybe you want to calculate `P('print'|'floral')` by `model.score("print", ["floral"])`?

more examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54979617/11267960