# NLTK Perplexity measure inversion

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk

I have given a train text and a test text. What I want to do is to train a language model by train data to calculate the perplexity of the test data.

This is my code:

```
import os
import requests
import io #codecs
from nltk.util import everygrams
from nltk.lm.preprocessing import pad_both_ends

from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize 

fileTest = open("AaronPressman.txt","r");
with io.open('AaronPressman.txt', encoding='utf8') as fin:
        textTest = fin.read()
if os.path.isfile('AaronPressmanEdited.txt'):
    with io.open('AaronPressmanEdited.txt', encoding='utf8') as fin:
        text = fin.read()

# Tokenize the text.
tokenized_text = [list(map(str.lower, word_tokenize(sent))) 
                for sent in sent_tokenize(text)]

from nltk.lm.preprocessing import padded_everygram_pipeline
from nltk.lm import Laplace

n = 1
padded_bigrams = list(pad_both_ends(word_tokenize(textTest), n=1))
trainTest = everygrams(padded_bigrams, min_len = n , max_len=n);

train_data, padded_sents = padded_everygram_pipeline(n, tokenized_text)


model = Laplace(n) 
model.fit(train_data, padded_sents)

print(model.perplexity(trainTest))
```

When I run this code with n=1, which is unigram, I get `"1068.332393940235"`. With n=2, or bigram, I get `"1644.3441077259993"`, and with trigrams I get `2552.2085752565313`.

What is the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are creating the test data is wrong (lower case train data but test data is not coverted to lowercase. Start and end tokens missing in test data). Try this

```
import os
import requests
import io #codecs
from nltk.util import everygrams
from nltk.lm.preprocessing import pad_both_ends
from nltk.lm.preprocessing import padded_everygram_pipeline
from nltk.lm import Laplace
from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize 

"""
fileTest = open("AaronPressman.txt","r");
with io.open('AaronPressman.txt', encoding='utf8') as fin:
        textTest = fin.read()
if os.path.isfile('AaronPressmanEdited.txt'):
    with io.open('AaronPressmanEdited.txt', encoding='utf8') as fin:
        text = fin.read()
"""
textTest = "This is an ant. This is a cat"
text = "This is an orange. This is a mango"

n = 2
# Tokenize the text.
tokenized_text = [list(map(str.lower, word_tokenize(sent))) 
                for sent in sent_tokenize(text)]
train_data, padded_sents = padded_everygram_pipeline(n, tokenized_text)

tokenized_text = [list(map(str.lower, word_tokenize(sent))) 
                for sent in sent_tokenize(textTest)]
test_data, padded_sents = padded_everygram_pipeline(n, tokenized_text)

model = Laplace(1) 
model.fit(train_data, padded_sents)

s = 0
for i, test in enumerate(test_data):
    p = model.perplexity(test)
    s += p

print ("Perplexity: {0}".format(s/(i+1)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but i think u missed a little thing, you should pass n into lapalce function,am i right?

Comment: Can u explain why u summed up all perplexities? is this correct?

Comment: The value passed to the lapalce is the smoothing parameter which is normally > 0. It has nothing to do with the n (unigram or bigram or ngram).

We are calculating the perplexity of each test sentence (since the perplexity method only accepts single generator not a list of generators) and finally average them (as you can see in the print statement). So the perplexity = s/(i+1)

Comment: Okay, so if i want to use MLE for example i have to pass n,right?

Comment: Yes for MLE highest ngram (i.e. n in your case) has to be passed

Comment: Thanks for your help, and one more little question, how can i score a sentence for detecting the writer? just pass the entire text to "score" method?

Comment: If your goal is to detect writer from a sentence then it is not a language modeling problem but a classification problem.

Comment: There is a similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999684/why-perplexity-for-padded-vocabulary-is-infinitive-for-nltk-lm-bigram

Comment: I found an error in your code, u passed padded_sentence of test data to fit function,i think this wrong!

Comment: and if you edit it it will start to give wrong values to perplexities! can you fix it?