# Why perplexity for padded vocabulary is infinitive for nltk.lm bigram?

Tags: python, nltk

I am testing the `perplexity` measure for a language model for a text:

```
  train_sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(train_text)
  test_sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(test_text)

  train_tokenized_text = [list(map(str.lower, nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sent))) 
                for sent in train_sentences]

  test_tokenized_text = [list(map(str.lower, nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sent))) 
                for sent in test_sentences]

  from nltk.lm.preprocessing import padded_everygram_pipeline
  from nltk.lm import MLE,Laplace
  from nltk.lm import Vocabulary

  vocab = Vocabulary(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(train_text),1);

  n = 2
  print(train_tokenized_text)
  print(len(train_tokenized_text))
  train_data, padded_vocab = padded_everygram_pipeline(n, train_tokenized_text)

  # print(list(vocab),"\n >>>>",list(padded_vocab))
  model = MLE(n) # Lets train a 3-grams maximum likelihood estimation model.
  # model.fit(train_data, padded_vocab)
  model.fit(train_data, vocab)

  sentences = test_sentences
  print("len: ",len(sentences))
  print("per all", model.perplexity(test_text))
```

When I use `vocab` in `model.fit(train_data, vocab)` the perplexity in `print("per all", model.perplexity(test_text))` is a number (`30.2`), but if I use `padded_vocab` which has additional `<s>` and `</s>` it prints `inf`.

Answer (score 3):

The input to perplexity is text in ngrams not a list of strings. You can verify the same by running

```
for x in test_text:
    print ([((ngram[-1], ngram[:-1]),model.score(ngram[-1], ngram[:-1])) for ngram in x])
```

You should see that the tokens(ngrams) are all wrong.

You will still get inf in the perplexity if your words in test data are out of vocab (of train data)

```
train_sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(train_text)
test_sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(test_text)

train_sentences = ['an apple', 'an orange']
test_sentences = ['an apple']

train_tokenized_text = [list(map(str.lower, nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sent))) 
                for sent in train_sentences]

test_tokenized_text = [list(map(str.lower, nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sent))) 
                for sent in test_sentences]

from nltk.lm.preprocessing import padded_everygram_pipeline
from nltk.lm import MLE,Laplace
from nltk.lm import Vocabulary

n = 1
train_data, padded_vocab = padded_everygram_pipeline(n, train_tokenized_text)
model = MLE(n)
# fit on padded vocab that the model know the new tokens added to vocab (<s>, </s>, UNK etc)
model.fit(train_data, padded_vocab) 

test_data, _ = padded_everygram_pipeline(n, test_tokenized_text)
for test in test_data:
    print("per all", model.perplexity(test))

# out of vocab test data
test_sentences = ['an ant']
test_tokenized_text = [list(map(str.lower, nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sent))) 
                for sent in test_sentences]
test_data, _ = padded_everygram_pipeline(n, test_tokenized_text)
for test in test_data:
    print("per all [oov]", model.perplexity(test))
```

Comment: Thanks, I have two questions, what if I want to use "bigrams" and not "everygrams" for train and test? and what if I want to calculate the perplexity for the all sentences? Should I get an average of the perplexities?

Comment: This is a good answer because it works with NLTK 3.4. Is there a way to get the probability of sentence from the model: eg `model.score(sentence)`? I don't understand why NLTK only provides `model.score(word,context)`.

Comment: @Ahmad I think perplexity should be only computed for many sentences. If you look at the documentation `model.perplexity(sentences)` works off the box. I don't understand why in this answer perplexity is computed by sentence.